# Why are the Ubuntu SDK Publish and Devices tab blank?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, installed the Ubuntu SDK, and created an app from the "HTML5 App" template.

Publish tab:
[image: Publish tab]

Devices tab:
[image]

Comment: I had that and also I've seen the same question here on askubuntu recently.

Comment: I don't know how it reappeared for me, but you can blindly try some things like adding ppa:phablet-team/tools or ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa and upgrading. Maybe QtCreator has some logs if it doesn't see these plugins. Also verify that chroots of ubuntu-sdk are created, have sessions and functional (using some ubuntu schroot guide from wiki).

Comment: ...seems to have worked! Thanks! If you move your comment to an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Only you now have precise steps to fix it, so make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [instructions for installing the SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/) tell you to add the ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa PPA. However, it seems that some updates from the phablet-team/tools PPA are also required for it to work correctly. Running

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

made the UI of the Publish and Devices tabs appear, and allowed me to create an emulator.