# Ubuntu SDK unable to start in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 14.10, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

in Ubuntu 15.05 I installed Ubuntu SDK, but I can't start it.
I installed in Terminal: `sudo apt install qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu`
And all dependencies. 292 new installed

When I try to start in the dash: QT-Creator
It starts, and after a few seconds I get a pop up window:
Updates are available for your kits. Please select those which should be updated.

I selecting `ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf`

Download starts and then:

```
Fetched 1073 kB in 6s (163 kB/s) Reading package lists...

E: 10mount: umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-c549e4e7-8eba-41b0-8970-2d761b1c5c9b/home/alex: target is busy E: 10mount: (In some cases useful info about processes that E: 10mount: use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)  E: click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-c549e4e7-8eba-41b0-8970-2d761b1c5c9b: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-stop Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf -- apt-get update --yes 
---Click exited with errors, please check the output---
```

The only thing I can do is close the window.

I don't know what to do. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Normally, `ubuntu-sdk` from `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa` and `ppa:phablet-team/tools`should be installed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/609241/why-are-the-ubuntu-sdk-publish-and-devices-tab-blank/609544#609544 And after that, if updates don't work, the kits can be recreated.

Comment: Is there still no solution to develop things for Ubuntu Phone? I really would like to code some apps or scopes, but I can't use that in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Don't post additional info as an answer. Add it to the question. Because I was notified just now (when you posted a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Then to the next step.

Don't update them. Go to Tools -> Options -> Ubuntu, and delete all "Click Targets". Then recreate the 14.10-armhf.